# Trying to set Fiddler as a Reverse Proxy

Tags: fiddler, reverse-proxy

I have been trying to set Fiddler as a Reverse Proxy, I've been following these instructions, but I just don't understand the point 3.

Option #1: Configure Fiddler as a Reverse-Proxy
Fiddler can be configured so that any traffic sent to http://127.0.0.1:8888 is automatically sent to a different port on the same machine.  To set this configuration:

1. Start REGEDIT
2. Create a new DWORD named ReverseProxyForPort inside HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fiddler2.
3. Set the DWORD to the local port you'd like to re-route inbound traffic to (generally port 80 for a standard HTTP server)
4. Restart Fiddler
5. Navigate your browser to http://127.0.0.1:8888

How can I set the DWORD to the local port??? Sorry Im novice in network connections, please hope some good fellaw could explain step by step how can I do that. Do I have to do it inside Fiddler? Do I have to do it in windows? Im using windows8.1

PD: I know Im missing that step, cuz after doing steps 4 and 5 I get this message in the browser: "[Fiddler] The connection to '127.0.0.1' failed. 
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888"

EDIT>

When I set on fiddler>Fiddler Options>Connections>Fiddler listens on port: 8888
I get the same message, but instead of 127.0.0.1:8888 now I get 127.0.0.1:80

[Fiddler] The connection to 'localhost' failed. 
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80

I have notice that in fiddler set reverse proxy page, it says...
Configure Fiddler as Reverse Proxy:
To use this method, the hostname for the request to reroute must be 127.0.0.1:8888, localhost:8888, [::1]:8888, or the machine's NETBIOS hostname on port 8888.

Is perhaps that why I can't get it to work? how can I set my machine NETBIOS hostname on port 8888?

Comment: Did you try setting it to `80`? That's usually the default for `http`.

Comment: How can I do that, that's what I don't know how to do

Comment: If you did step 2, then set that `DWORD` (by double-clicking it) value to `80` (decimal) that's it.

Comment: I have try that (80 and decimal), then I restart fiddler, but I got the same error message, any  hint??

Comment: Do you still have fiddler open when you try it, and is port 80/8888 open in your firewall?

Comment: Yes I restarted fiddler, port 8888 is TCP right? Well, I allowed TCP port 8888 in the windows firewall, restart fiddler, but I got the same ERRor

Comment: you mean, two ports, 80 and 8888 right? create to rules in windows firewall, right? Well I did exactly that, allow port 80 and 8888 (inboud rules) restart fiddler and I got the same result.

Comment: If I try to create a fiddler rule... `if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "webserver:8888") oSession.host = "webserver:80";` then I get this message when connecting in the browser... [Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "webserver" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No such host is known

Comment: Try changing `webserver` to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: No, it doesn;t work neither. SOMETHING I have notice is that DWORD is automatically change to hex everytime, that is normal right? I tried to change webserver for localhost, or webserver for 127.0.0.1 with the same error result

Comment: It shouldn't be hexadecimal... is the number still 80? decimal 80 is not the same as hexadecimal 80.

Comment: I type 80 in decimal, but after I close that window, I guess it converts it to hex cuz it also changes 80 to 50. If I type 8888 in decimal, it converts it to a number with letters in hex. So I guess that is not the problem it just convert whatever I type into hex. There must be another thing, I gues is the NETBIOS hostname, do you know how to change it???

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue... this fixed it...

1. In the menu click 'Tools' >> 'Fiddler options' >> 'Connections'
2. Find out the port number

Use the port number noted here instead! e.g. http://127.0.0.1:[port number]

Answer (score 0):

Let's step back a bit. Why *specifically* are you trying to run Fiddler as a Reverse Proxy? What service are you trying to pass traffic into (e.g. IIS?) What port did you move that service to? What is the exact (original) URL of the traffic you're trying to collect?

You don't need to mess with the registry if you're going to write FiddlerScript.

Comment: Thanks @EricLaw, finally I solved using PowerShell instead of Fiddler, cuz I was trying to communicate with a TCP socket. I really appreciate your intereset, Thanks anyway man. Best Regards.

Comment: PD: I do have another question related to PowerShell and Skype, hope you could give me a hand with that... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063854/is-it-possible-to-tweak-skype-basic-settings-using-powershell ThanksAdvanced.